# How $g(f(x))=f(g(x))=x$ makes $f(x)$ and $g(f(x))$ inverse of each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

If f(x) and g(x) are two functions, they would be inverse of each other when the following holds,$$ g(f(x))=f(g(x))=x $$ If we pick $f(x) = x+5$ and $g(x)= x-5$ we can see the truth of this fact. But I am thinking for some simple linguistic explanation of why actually this equation holds for all inverse functions.

Comment: You're asking why, for inverse functions $f$ and $g$, we have $$f(g(x))=x=g(f(x))$$? Well this is by definition of an invertible function. The idea of this equation is that $f$ "undoes" $g$ and vice-versa, because applying them consecutively in either order returns the original argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just imagine there is an arrow (taken by $f$) from $x$ to $f(x)$, as $g(f(x))=x$, this means that there is an arrow (taken by $g$) from $f(x)$ to $x$, the arrow by $g$ is just a reverse arrow taken by $f$, so can you see that at the end $x$ stays at the original place?

Answer (score 3):

By definition of $f^{-1}$ we have:$$y= f(x)\Longleftrightarrow x =f^{-1}(y)$$

Since we have $g(f(x))=x$ we have $g(y)=x$ which makes $g=f^{-1}$

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I think that the use of notation here is quite valuable.  If we think of $X$ and $Y$ as the domains of $f$ and $f^{-1}$, respectively, using $x\in X$ as an input for $f$ and $y\in Y$ as an input for $f^{-1}$ significantly clarifies what is happening.  While it is not mathematically necessary to make this notational distinction, it is sound pedagogy.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply showing that the function g takes the output y of f(x) and gives back the input x.

Comment: It’s not critical here, but please consider using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) when composing your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Worth a bit of caution about, for example, trigonometric functions, when the nice relation needs some adjustment when $x$ is outside some standard interval.

When $- \pi/2 < x < \pi/2,$ we do get $\arctan \tan x = x.$ However, for  $ \pi/2 < x < 3 \pi/2,$ we do get $\arctan \tan x = x - \pi.$ 
So, for instance, $\tan 5 \pi / 4 = 1.$ But $\arctan 1 = \pi/4 = 5\pi/4 - \pi$

Most important, fairly standard, functions, have some such difficulty. The pair $e^x, \log x$ are unusually well behaved

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, substitute $ x \rightarrow f(x)$, so $f(f^{-1}(f(x)))=f(x)$ now apply $f^{-1}$ to this
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{-1}(f(\color{red}{f^{-1}(f(x))}))= \color{red}{f^{-1}(f(x))} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now replace $ f^{-1}(f(y)) \rightarrow y$ and we have $ f^{-1}(f(y))=y$.